# TextMate: open file windows is weird

Tags: textmate

In TextMate, I have recently my open file that is become weird:

[image: Textmate open file]

No way to come back to a normal window.

Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.TextMate.preview.plist` file while TextMate is closed and then reopen it.

Note: You might want to backup the file first before deleting it.